# Express routes appending the URL instead of overwriting

Tags: node.js, express

**EDIT:**

Views are super simple for now as I'm just trying to layout the routes set with the navbar...

```
ul.nav.in#side-menu
    li.sidebar-search
        div.input-group.custom-search-form
            input(type='text', class='form-control', placeholder='Search contacts...')
            span.input-group-btn
                button.btn.btn-default(type='button')
                    i.fa.fa-search
    li
        a(href='/')
            i.fa.fa-dashboard.fa-fw 
            &nbspDashboard
    li
        a(href='#')
            i.fa.fa-user.fa-fw 
            &nbspContacts
            span.fa.arrow
        ul.nav.nav-second-level.collapse
            li
                a(href='contacts/investors') Investors
            li
                a(href='contacts/agents') Agents
```

Simple question I'm sure. My links on my home page are appending and adding to the URL instead of requesting with a new URL.

Routes file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlData = require('../controllers/data')
var ctrlPageBuilder = require('../controllers/pageBuilder')

router.get('/', ctrlPageBuilder.renderHomePage);
router.get('/contacts/investors', ctrlPageBuilder.renderInvestorsPage);
router.get('/contacts/agents', ctrlPageBuilder.renderAgentsPage);
router.get('/contacts/vendors', ctrlPageBuilder.renderVendorsPage);
router.get('/properties', ctrlPageBuilder.renderPropertiesPage);

module.exports = router;
```

Then my controller

```
//Controllers to render pages on the browser
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'

module.exports.renderHomePage = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'REA Dashboard'});
};

module.exports.renderInvestorsPage = function(req, res) {
    res.render('investors', {title: 'Investors'});
};

module.exports.renderAgentsPage = function(req, res) {
    res.render('agents', {title: 'Agents'});
};

....
```

The code renders this in a production environment:

```
On page load   : http://localhost:3000
Click Investors: http://localhost:3000/contacts/investors
Click Agents   : http://localhost:3000/contacts/contacts/agents
                    404 ERROR
```

Comment: Your templates probably contain relative paths instead of absolute paths. Make sure there is a `/` before `contacts/...` in your `href` attributes.

Comment: Can you share your views that render those links?

Comment: Does your view folder contain index, investors and agents files?

Comment: I added an edit above